# something i missed here, style in PHP table row works partly!

Tags: php, css, class

no border shows up when setting style in the table row below, inside the while loop? why? Background color setting works fine, but not this... NO BORDER SHOWS UP...

```
    // Build Result String
$display_table = "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){

$display_table .= "<tr style='border-top-width: thin; border-top-style: solid;'>"; //  wont work here, why????? But if I set bgr color to something, the bgr color works, but not the border thing... hmmmmmm

$display_table .= "<td width='110' rowspan='2'>BILD HÄR</td>";
$display_table .= "<td width='377' height='15'>$row[headline]</td>";
$display_table .= "<td width='67' rowspan='2'>$row[insert_date]</td>";
$display_table .= "</tr>";
$display_table .= "<tr>";
$display_table .= "<td height='15'>$row[price]:-</td>";
$display_table .= "</tr>";
}

$display_table .= "</table>";
echo $display_table;
```

Comment: You really want a border around the TD elements don't you?

Comment: how more questions do you have about those few lines of code? You could learn a bit about css and html at de.selfhtml.org (I assumed you speak german :)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

css doesnt always work on the tr element because it's just a container tag, try putting a class on the tr and using the stylesheet to style it up

e.g.:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .myrow td
    {
        border-top:solid 1px black;
    }

</style>

<table>
    <tr class="myrow">
        <td>...
```

Answer (score 3):

Rows don't have borders.  Cells do.  Move `border-top-style: solid` to the `td` elements within the `tr`.

Comment: <table> does have border too. Just do complement your comment.

Comment: CSS. Confusing the hell out of everyone since 1996.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using these styles

```
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

td {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```